# About Schur theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, schur-complement

Schur theorem: Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional inner product space $V$, Suppose that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits, then there exists an orthonormal basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that the matrix $[T]_\beta$ is upper triangular.

**Proof:** by math induction on the dimension $n$ of $V$. When $n=1$, the result is immediate. Suppose the result is true for linear operators on $(n-1)$ dimensional inner product spaces whose characteristic polynomials split. We can assume that $T^{*}$ has a unit eigenvector $z$. suppose that $T^{*}(z)+\lambda z$ and that $W=\text{span }({z})$. We show that $W^{\bot} $ is T-invariant ***(Why?)*** If $y \in W^{\bot} $and $x=cz \in W$, then $\langle T(y,x \rangle= \langle T(y),cz \rangle= \langle y,T^{*}(cz) \rangle=\langle y, cT^{*}(z) \rangle= \langle y, c\lambda z \rangle= \langle \overline{c\lambda} y,z \rangle= \overline{c \lambda}(0)=0$.

So $T(y) \in W^{\bot}$. It is easy to show that the characteristic polynomial of $T_{W^{\bot}}$ divides the characteristic polynomial of T and hence splits. By theorem (suppose $S=\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is an orthonormal set in an $n-$dimensional inner product space $V$, then if $W$ is any subspace of $V$, then $\dim(V)=\dim(W)+\dim(W^{\bot}))$, $\dim(W^{\bot})=n-1$ ***(Why n-1)?***, so we apply the induction hypothesis to $T_{W^{\bot}}$ and obtain an orthonormal basis$ \gamma $ of $W^{\bot}$ such that $[T_{W^{\bot}}]_{\gamma}$ is upper triangular. Clearly, $\beta = \gamma \cup {z}$ is an orthonormal basis for V such that $[T]_\beta$ is upper triangular.

Over all, is there a more concise proof for this theorem?

Comment: Schur's theorem is a result that is explained and proved in many linear algebra texts (for instance: Friedberg, Insel, Spence; Hoffman and Kunze).  There are also proofs available online, such as [this proof from the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition#Proof).  Have you looked at any of these?  If so, then where exactly do you need help?

Comment: Perhaps you're asking for a "simplest" approach because you have seen a proof that was difficult to follow.  If that is the case, then could you please clarify what approach you would like to avoid?

Comment: The quickest proof I know is to invoke a fairly strong result (existence of Jordan canonical form). Since the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits, it has a JCF; i.e there exists a basis $\alpha$ such that $[T]_{\alpha}$ is a Jordan matrix (in particular upper triangular). Now apply the Grahm-Schmidt process to $\alpha$ to get an orthonormal basis $\beta$. The construction of Grahm-schmidt shows that $[T]_{\beta}$ will still be upper-triangular.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thanks, jordan canonical is beyond my reach. Going to learn that soon though

Comment: basically all you need is some way of proving that if the characteristic polynomial splits, then there exists a basis $\alpha$ such that $[T]_{\alpha}$ is upper-triangular (just FYI, the converse is clearly true). For example, this can be done by induction. I only quoted Jordan canonical form because that's a fairly standard (though high-powered) theorem.  But once you find a basis which makes it upper-triangular, just apply Grahm-Schmidt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a preliminary lemma:

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and let $T: V \to V$ be a linear map. Then, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits over $F$ if and only if there exists a basis $\alpha$ of $V$ such that $[T]_{\alpha}$ is an upper-triangular matrix.

Note that $\Leftarrow$ is almost trivial. For $\implies$ (which is what you need), you can try an argument by induction (and perhaps use quotient spaces). This is definitely a worthwhile exercise to prove on its own.

Once you establish the lemma, all you need is to apply Grahm-Schmidt process to $\alpha$ to obtain an orthonormal basis $\beta$ of $V$. Then, $[T]_{\beta}$ will still be upper-triangular; because the construction of Grahm-Schmidt shows that if $\alpha = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, and $\beta = \{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$, then for each $1 \leq k \leq n$, we have
\begin{align}
\text{span}\{x_1, \dots, x_k\} = \text{span}\{y_1, \dots, y_k\}
\end{align}
(if this isn't immediately clear, then review the proof of the Grahm-Schmidt process). I leave the details for you to verify.

---

Note that it is not necessary at all to invoke the existence of a Jordan canonical form for linear operators whose characteristic polynomial splits. I only said that because it gives an extremely quick proof of what you are after (but of course, this lemma I wrote above is much easier to prove than the existence of a JCF).